# how to automatically resize jPanel

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I´ve created through NEtBeans design of jframe, when its components is created automatically.
Now I put on this jFrame component jLayeredPane called agendaLayer, cause I need more panes here and switch.
I´ve set horizontal and vertical resize to layout that component belong so it is automatically resize to some value when windows (jFrame) is resized..

Then I´ve created also through designer new class stock which extends jPanel,

now I put this jPanel to JLayredPane and need to get its properties about resizable..

```
stock st = new stock();
st.setBounds(0,0,agendaLayer.getWidth(),agendaLayer.getHeight());      
agendaLayer.add(st);
```

But It did not work, jLayredPane is automatically resized when window is changed, but jPanel not it remains the same..

Comment: You can't do it without forcing it, i.e. on resizing the jLayeredPane then go and resize the containers, if you want it to be auto without more code, then you will need another root container.

Answer (score 1):

> , jLayredPane is automaticaly resized when window is changed, but jPanel not it remains the same..

A JLayeredPane uses a null layout by default so components are never resized.

> cause I need more panes here and switch.

If you need to switch panels then use a CardLayout. See the Swing tutorial on [Using a Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into layout managers:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html